# Nodejs: Read from redis and write to file

Tags: node.js, redis

What I'm trying to do is pretty basic: I want to iterate through a collection of redis keys and write the values to a file. The code I have works, however I am using streams to write to file and it's extremely slow (500k rows in 65 minutes).

What other approaches can I take?

Here is the code:

```
var fileDest = path.join(config.get('rootPath'), 'redisData_' + Date.now() + '.csv');    
var file = fs.createWriteStream(fileDest);
file.on('error', function (err) { 
    console.log(err); 
});
async.each(keys, function (key, callback) {
    clientSlave.get(key, function (err, reply) {
        var str = key + ',' + reply + '\n';
        file.write(str);
        callback();        
    });
}, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log('done');
        file.end();
    }
});
```

Comment: Make sure you're checking errors passed by `clientSlave.get()`. Also, try to determine where the slowness is coming from: retrieving data from Redis, or writing the file.

Comment: @robertklep, I checked to see where the slowness might be originating from and it's definitely when writing to file. It's writing in chunks, and for 500,000 rows it takes roughly 60 minutes.

Comment: How large are your records? Writing 1M rows using code similar to yours (without the Redis part) takes about 13 seconds (which I still find a tad slow, but it's certainly not taking 60 minutes). [Here](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/84b467120b0c00c1455f) is the gist I tested with.

Comment: Ok, so after testing your gist on my local machine and on the server, I've concluded that there is a problem writing to file on the server. On my local machine it took ~15 seconds, while on the server it's still writing to file as I respond to this comment. I think there might be a problem with the server's ulimit values.

Comment: Sounds like it might also be time to check the [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) status on your server, may be a disk that's failing.

Comment: It's a google compute engine VM instance with a 40GB SSD running Ubuntu 14.04. I would be surprised if it were a failing disk but I will check that as well.

Comment: I don't have experience with Google, but with AWS you can have IOPS limits imposed on your VM which makes writing slow (although in your case it's _way_ too slow).